# More configurable gmail filtering

Tags: email, gmail

Gmail filters are a pain because it's hard to make them hierarchical (i.e. you can't say, "Apply this filter first, then based on the result of that, apply this other filter"), and you [cannot filter by contact groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20020/how-to-add-filter-and-label-to-group-in-gmail-contacts) or even [by contacts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40237/gmail-search-filter-from-contacts-possible). I have a specific set of rules for how I want my e-mail configured.

Is there any, preferably FOSS, software that will retrieve my e-mail and apply filters as I desire? Ideally, I'd do something like set up a gmail filter dropping everything into some label like "unfiltered" (skipping the inbox), then I'd have an always-on device that would receive push notifications from that folder and apply my filters. I would not be OK if this caused push notifications for things that do in fact hit the inbox to fail.

A less ideal situation would be a mail server that I control to which I forward all my incoming e-mail and filter based on that. I am worried about reliability and the complexity of sending e-mails without being spam-blackholed when running my own mail server.

I should explicitly note that any e-mail *client* that does this should be syncing the labels back with gmail. This is something I'm envisioning running from a raspberry pi connected to an always-on connection.